# Polymorphism and non-virtual derived class methods

Tags: c++, polymorphism

**Consider the following code:**

```
class Human
{
    virtual void Walk() = 0;
}

class Male : public Human
{
    void Walk();
}

class Female : public Human
{
    void Walk();
    Human* GiveBirth();
}

int main()
{
    vector<Human*> people;
    people.push_back(new Female);
}
```

Let's say I want to call GiveBirth() from the base class pointer, I would have these options:

**1-** Cast the pointer to the derived type

```
people.push_back( dynamic_cast<Female*>(people[0])->GiveBirth() );
```

Reason why I don't use it:

I need to make my program in a way that all derived classes are unknown by the user/programmer (even if it's logical to say that such a method is female related).

**2-** Make GiveBirth() method virtual

Reason why I don't use it:

This method would now be visible to Male class, which is everything but logical.

**3-** Use the 'Curiously Recurring Template Pattern'

Reason why I don't use it:

I don't know. Maybe I'm wrong with the usage of this pattern, but I think I could not create a global pointer to instantiate my derived classes since the base class is a template and it needs to know the type at compile time.

**Is there any other program structure that could do what I want to achieve?**

Comment: This sounds like bad design. You have clearly contradicting goals: "The client code must only be aware of the general objects, but it must use some operations *not* applicable to the general objects." Can you elaborate on why this is the case?

Comment: Try the Visitor Pattern, a.k.a. Double Dispatch. BTW: You should better use dynamic_cast to a reference, because that will signal failure using an exception instead of causing UB due to the null-pointer dereference.

Comment: Agree with others that it sounds like a bad design, but anyway... you could have `bool canGiveBirth()` in the base class and and only cast to `Female` if the instance can give birth. Depending how generic you want to be this could get unwieldy (think of a general animals case with `canBite()`, `eatsMeat()`, `canFly()` - there is not 1:1 mapping of "abilities" to type.

Comment: Assume you have released `Human` class and its associated documentation. Now document `GiveBirth` at a very high level (language-independent—just assume the language gives you whatever you want). How, when, and why should your users call it?

Comment: `Human* GiveBirth();` must be the funniest implementation of the Clone pattern I've ever seen. Bonus points for the non-constness.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in the base class should not be aware of functions in their derived classes or their behavior unless of course that functionality is required by the base class and the base class in return declares them as virtual or pure virtual.
In other words, the base class doesn't depend on the derived class. Code that does this create a circular dependency which should be avoided at all cost.

This means that you should declare or implement all the functions in the base class. If implemented, have them return an error (or throw an exception) so a derived class can override them with a proper implementation.

These functions in the base class will be `virtual` or pure virtual (preferred).

Example:

```
class Human
{
    virtual void Walk() = 0;
    Human* GiveBirth()  = 0;
}

class Male : public Human
{
    void Walk();
    Human* GiveBirth() { return NULL; }
}

class Female : public Human
{
    void Walk();
    Human* GiveBirth();
}
```

Comment: Concerning your initial comment, I have to disagree. It is often very useful when a baseclass defines an interface that derived classes have to implement and this often uses private functions that are only supposed to be called by the baseclass. Examples are the public/private pairs in std::streambuf. Concerning your other suggestion, this leads to lots of clutter in derived classes where most just returns null. Not all humans have the ability to give birth, so not all of them should even suggest that they support it. This is similar to the inheritance relation between an ellipse and a circle.

Comment: Reading it again, i see that the wording should be better. 10x for the feedback

Comment: I disagree on the "pure virtual (preferred)": If you need all humans to provide a function `GiveBirth()`, and some, or most implementations are just dummies like the one in `Male`, I think its more clean to provide the dummy implementation in the base class. Avoids cluttering your subclasses with repeated dummy implementations which may get out of sync and are a violation of the DRY principle.